# Error in XML Serialization c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, serialization

I'm working on a WCF service using .net 4.0 framework. I'm trying to serialize the request object using the same type which is already been deserialized by the encorder. but it keeps throwing off for "There was an error generating the XML document". is there anyway that i can get an descriptive error at least?

screenshot of the successfully deserialized request,

[image]

errornous code that supposed to serialize the object,

```
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ResourceParticipantDataRequest));
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    serializer.Serialize(writer, resourceParticipantData);
```

the Error,

```
    ----Inner Exception:
----Type: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
----Message: There was an error generating the XML document.
----Source: mscorlib
----StackTrace:
```

Please help! i'm running out of options.

Comment: when you use `serializer.Serialize`, is there an `InnerException` on the exception?

Comment: it's following,"The type OATI.Service.ContractModel.ReceiveResourceParticipantData.EquipmentContainer was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically."

Comment: so... Go do what the message says to do?

Comment: actually i don't really understand what it trying to say

Comment: it means: you've told it to expect a `Foo`, and it has actually received a different type of object. If this is a subclass of `Foo`, you can tell it to expect that subclass by annotating `Foo` with `[XmlInclude(typeof(TheSubclass))]`

Comment: You can check for KnownType Attribute in your data contract class. it may help you out. If class you want to serialize dont have known type attribute then it might get error in your serialization processs.

Comment: i was able to fix it. Thanks @MarcGravell